# Indian Railways Database Error connecting trains between stations

Tags: mysql, database

I have the database of mysql attached  of trains, train schedules, train numbers.

Now I want to query the trains between two stations like Jaipur to Jodhpur so I queried like this

```
SELECT distinct d1.train_no
FROM   train_schedule d1
INNER JOIN train_schedule d2 ON d2.train_no=d1.train_no
WHERE d1.stn_code = 'JU' and d2.stn_code = 'JP'
```

It's giving correct result but its showing both Jodhpur to Jaipur and Jaipur to Jodhpur trains so the result become doubles the train.

I want to query about the trains only from Jaipur to Jodhpur not the Jodhpur to Jaipur. And if I select date then matched trains must be found from the trains database.

Comment: I think the problem is with the caps lock key.

Comment: you are doing inner join .. can you try left join....?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977456/database-query-to-find-trains-between-two-stations-on-specific-date-like-irctc-c?noredirect=1#comment22777047_15977456

Answer (score 1):

You are not querying the trains table, but the train schedule table, meaning that the query doesn't give you 2 trains, it gives you 2 train schedules.

I'd start the SELECT from the trains table, like this:

```
SELECT trains.train_number, count(*) as "Number of schedules"
FROM trains
INNER JOIN train_schedule a USING (train_number) WHERE train_schedule.station_code = 'JU'
INNER JOIN train_schedule b USING (train_number) WHERE train_schedule.station_code = 'JP'
```

(Pseudo MySQL code)

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you join distinct records:

```
    SELECT distinct d1.train_no
      FROM train_schedule d1
INNER JOIN train_schedule d2 ON (     d2.train_no =  d1.train_no
                                  AND d2.stn_code <> d1.stn_code )
     WHERE d1.stn_code = 'JU'
       AND d2.stn_code = 'JP'
         ;
```

otherwise your result set will be populated with unwanted identity matches (representing fictitious train sections from one station to itself).