# database query to find trains between two stations on specific date like irctc.co.in

Tags: mysql, database

I have following database

#### Table structure for table `trains`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trains` (
    `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `train_no` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `train_name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `runsfrom` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `SUN` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `MON` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `TUE` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `WED` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `THU` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `FRI` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `SAT` varchar(3) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `DOE` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1912 ;
```

having data like this:

```
INSERT INTO `trains` VALUES (269, '12307', 'HWH JU  EXPRESS', 'HOWRAH JN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN', '2013-03-24');
INSERT INTO `trains` VALUES (270, '12308', 'JU HWH SUPFAST', 'JODHPUR JN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN', '2013-03-24');
INSERT INTO `trains` VALUES (381, '12461', 'MANDOR EXPRESS', 'DELHI', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN', '2013-03-24');
INSERT INTO `trains` VALUES (382, '12462', 'MANDOR EXPRESS', 'JODHPUR JN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN', '2013-03-24');
```

---

#### Table structure for table `train_number`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `train_number` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `train_no` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1912 ;
```

having data like this:

```
INSERT INTO `train_number` VALUES (269, '12307');
INSERT INTO `train_number` VALUES (270, '12308');
INSERT INTO `train_number` VALUES (381, '12461');
```

#### Table structure for table `train_schedule`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `train_schedule` (
    `train_no` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `stn_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `stn_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `route_no` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `arr_time` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `dep_time` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `halt_time` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `distance` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    `day` varchar(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

having data like this:

```
INSERT INTO `train_schedule` VALUES ('12307', 'HWH ', 'HOWRAH JN      ', '1', 'Sourc', '23:30', '', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `train_schedule` VALUES ('12307', 'BWN ', 'BARDDHAMAN JN  ', '1', '00:35', '00:37', '2:00', '95', '2');
INSERT INTO `train_schedule` VALUES ('12307', 'ASN ', 'ASANSOL JN     ', '1', '01:52', '01:56', '4:00', '200', '2');
INSERT INTO `train_schedule` VALUES ('12307', 'DHN ', 'DHANBAD JN     ', '1', '03:05', '03:15', '10:00', '259', '2');
```

Now I want to find to find the trains between two stations **on specific date**. So I tried with this query

```
SELECT distinct d1.train_no
FROM   train_schedule d1
INNER JOIN train_schedule d2 ON d2.train_no=d1.train_no
WHERE d1.stn_code = 'JU' and d2.stn_code = 'JP'
```

But it's showing both data from JU to JP and from JP to JU also so it makes the result double.

I want to make this query correct only for one direction  **on a specific date** as days when it runs is also given in database

Comment: The structure of your tables dosen't seem right, you have a trains table and a train_number table (which doesn't seem to have valuable fields)

Comment: if you dont mind it seems both are same tables.. so we can remove the train_number table as its not used longer.. so whats now boss

Comment: I meant it better normalization, Anyways, you mention you need to get the trains bw 2 stations, does this mean that if there are 2 stations A,D (you need to get all trains halted at stations A,B,C & D?

Comment: yes boss you right if there are 10 stations bw the A and D then all trains halted at that 10 stations... 
if possible can u make it a best database for good use

Comment: how do you which stations fall within 2 stations? Is this stored?

Comment: yes its recordred if you dont mind can i send u a small database of the demo data ? can i mail you if u dont mind

Comment: You can add a few rows of the required tables on SQLFiddle and share the link here, it shall other user's too

Comment: the thing which i want to tell you is a demo of some rows so i can send it to your mail id or other place if u can help plz

Comment: http://www.2shared.com/document/kTJD_-xV/final_database.html this is dwnload link

Comment: the SQL you posted doesn't seem clear, you mention that you are storing the stations between 2 stations, but that doesn't seem to be case

Comment: the story behind the data is its as it is available from the indianraiways.gov.in..
when we find a train schedule then its shows the train schedule
in the above format.. so i saved all the data in my db in same format
its having all the details of stations ,halt time,source,destination so

Comment: hey have a look here .. i hv data here http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/#PMAURL-0:index.php?db=&table=&server=2&target=&token=1de7636806724eac8adb645b1d0b03a8
db name is irctc

Comment: It might help if you include the expected data returning (with sample data in the db).

Comment: hello sel as i above uploaded the db file in 2shared.com 
http://www.2shared.com/document/kTJD_-xV/final_database.html
 expected data is in terms of like
all the train nos which for the place between JU to JP for example

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, to answer the part to return only one direction, please try the query below:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM   train_schedule d1
INNER JOIN train_schedule d2 ON d2.train_no=d1.train_no
WHERE d1.stn_code = 'JU' and d2.stn_code = 'JP' 
   AND d1.distance < d2.distance
```

JU (departure) will always have distance less than JP (arrival).

Comment: after this query i got the answer like 

train_no  stn_code  stn_name   route_no  arr_time  dep_time  halt_time  distance  day
12308  JU    JODHPUR JN      1  Sourc  20:30   0  1
12462  JU    JODHPUR JN      1  Sourc  20:00   0  1
12464  JU    JODHPUR JN      1  Sourc  19:00   0  1
12466  JU    JODHPUR JN      1  Sourc  06:10   0  1
14660  JU    JODHPUR JN      1  22:25  23:00  35:00  301  1
14662  JU    JODHPUR JN      1  22:20  23:00  40:00  210  1
14853  JU    JODHPUR JN      1  17:00  Desti   1203  2
14854  JU    JODHPUR JN      1  Sourc  09:45

Comment: the resultant answer after running above query

[resultant query result](http://eservicesindia.com/irctc/asdf.jpeg)

Comment: after researching i found that
the 14853,14863,14865 trains are from JP TO JU so these are wrong result..
so what should we do next boss

Comment: i tried this but it shows the wrong result
SELECT d1.*,d2.distance
FROM   train_schedule d1
INNER JOIN train_schedule d2 ON d2.train_no=d1.train_no
WHERE d1.stn_code = 'JU' AND d2.stn_code = 'JP'  AND d1.distance <= d2.distance

its shwoing that data also who is greater than d1.distance

Comment: I can't download your db. Is it possible you put in the data into sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/7fff6/2  so that i could understand your question better? thanks.

Comment: dear sel as i said sqlfiddle doesnt allow me to post more text to create db or schema so
i gave the link of download file
please help if you can
[download file] (http://www.2shared.com/document/kTJD_-xV/final_database.html)

Comment: dear sel as you said i made schema at above sqlfiddle but the data is too long to submit.. and its not taking that

Comment: Sorry. can't download. U could insert a few rows of data instead of a whole bunch of it.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of sun...sat you should use 1..7 and make the value boolean or tinyint

```
 SELECT distinct d1.train_no
 FROM   train_schedule d1 WHERE DAYOFWEEK(#yyyy-dd-mm#) = 1
 INNER JOIN train_schedule d2 ON d2.train_no=d1.train_no
 WHERE d1.stn_code = 'JU' and d2.stn_code = 'JP'
```

This should work